# not all items in sensors output is shown (lm-sensors)

Tags: asus, lm-sensors

I have this build here: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/chWzjy

I did ran `sudo sensors-detect`

$ sensors output only shows CPU temps and no fans data at all.

Which software I need to install or kernel modules to load for that to work?

I installed ubuntu-server 18.04 for minimal setup.

at work I have this sensors output:

```
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan: 3413 RPM
Video Fan:     3329 RPM
CPU:            +60.0°C
Ambient:        +54.0°C
Ambient:        +59.0°C
SODIMM:         +52.0°C

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +62.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +61.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +59.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +60.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +62.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:     +0.86 V  (min =  +0.60 V, max =  +1.20 V)
temp1:        +54.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
```

which is more or less expected, at home only cpu section, and CPU fan speed says it's 0 RPM.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of my thinkpad adding thinkpad_acpi module did the trick, did you try to check here in case some module specific to Dell laptops is missing?

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fan_speed_control#Dell_laptops